# Insert a new inner object into array of objects observable array and update the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

**HTML with bindings:**

```
<div class="container" data-bind="foreach: { data: Conferences, as: 'conf' }">
    <div class="conf" data-bind="attr: { id : conf.Id }">
        <div class="conf-month" data-bind="text: conf.StartTime"></div>
        <div class="conf-day" data-bind="text: conf.EndTime"></div>
        <div class="add-user">
            <input type="tel" data-bind="value: $root.PhoneNumber />
            <input type="email" data-bind="value: $root.Email" />
            <a id="add-user" title="Add new user" data-bind="attr: { value: conf.Id }, click: $root.addUserToConference">Add</a>
        </div>
        <div class="conf-users" data-bind="foreach: { data: conf.ConferenceUsers, as: 'user' }">
            <div class="conf-user" data-bind="attr: { id: 'confuser-' + user.Id}">
                <span data-bind="text: user.Name"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: user.PhoneNumber"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: user.Email"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**KnockoutJs ViewModel:**

```
function ConferenceViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.Conferences = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.PhoneNumber = ko.observable("");
    self.Email = ko.observable("");


self.getAllConfs = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/confs/getconfs',
        }).done(function (confs) {
            $.each(confs, function (index, conf) {
                    //populate the list on document ready
                    confVm.Conferences.push(conf);
            };
        }).fail(showError);
}

self.addUserToConference  = function (viewModel, event) {
    var user = {
        "Id": 0,
        "ConferenceId": viewModel.Id(),
        "Email": "self.Email()",
        "PhoneNumber": self.PhoneNumber(),
    };  

    // here we should insert a new ConferenceUser into the Conferences observable array
    // and also update the DOM 

    // ajax to insert user to db
}
```

After I populate the above Conferences observableArray via ajax, 
the output of `console.log(ko.toJSON(confVm.Conferences()))` is as follows:

```
[  
   {  
      "ConferenceUsers":[  
         {  
            "Id":3006,
            "ConferenceId":8,
            "Name":null,
            "Email":"mail@lala.com",
            "UserName":null,
            "PhoneNumber":"234234234234",
            "ChannelId":null,
            "State":null,
            "Type":null,
            "RecordingId":null
         }
      ],
      "Id":8,
      "Subject":"YYYhaaaaa",
      "StartTime":"2016-05-29T18:30:00",
      "EndTime":"2016-05-29T19:30:00",
      "OrganizerEmail":"elpas@live.com",
      "OrganizerName":"dasdasd",
      "Pin":"6402",
      "BridgeId":null,
      "State":null
   },
   {  
      "ConferenceUsers":[  
         {  
            "Id":3013,
            "ConferenceId":12,
            "Name":null,
            "Email":"dsfdfsdfdsf@dfdfdf.com",
            "UserName":null,
            "PhoneNumber":null,
            "ChannelId":null,
            "State":null,
            "Type":null,
            "RecordingId":null
         }
      ],
      "Id":12,
      "Subject":"dsfsdfdsfsdf",
      "StartTime":"2016-05-31T22:00:00",
      "EndTime":"2016-05-31T23:00:00",
      "OrganizerEmail":"d@adssad.com",
      "OrganizerName":"dsfdsfsdf",
      "Pin":"3402",
      "BridgeId":null,
      "State":null
   }
]
```

**Q:** How can I insert a new ConferenceUser by ConferenceId and update the DOM accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to execute four steps:

1. Get the current list of conferences from the observable array `Conferences`
2. Find the conference with the right id
3. Push a new user to this conference's `ConferenceUsers`
4. Make sure `Conferences` is set with the new data

While all steps are pretty straight forward to execute, there'll be some drawbacks to how they'd work:

The `Conference` objects and the `ConferenceUsers` arrays aren't observable. Knockout isn't automatically aware of any changes **inside** the `Conference` objects. So, after *step 3 and 4*, to knockout, it won't appear as if anything's changed: the `Conferences` array still has the same objects in it.

**My advice:**

If adding new users to conferences is something that will happen regularly, I'd suggest creating a `Conference` viewmodel that has a `ko.observableArray` of users. Alternatively, you could create *new* `Conference` objects for every minor change, which will trigger knockout to re-render the entire UI instead of just the relevant part (assuming you've used a `foreach` data-bind somewhere).

A quick example of how you could map your regular `Conference` objects to viewmodels:

```js
// Your JSON data from the ajax request (an array of objects)
var conferencesData = [];


var Conference = function(conferenceJSON) {

  // It's better to map all properties you're using individually, 
  // but this at least exposes the original JSON object
  this.props = conferenceJSON;

  this.users = ko.observableArray(conferenceJSON.conferenceUsers);

};

var createConference = function(conferenceJSON) {
  return new Conference(conferenceJSON);
};

var ConferenceList = function(conferencesJSON) {
  var self = this;

  this.conferences = ko.observableArray(conferencesJSON.map(createConference));

  this.addConference = function(conferenceJSON) {
    self.conferences.push(createConference(conferenceJSON));
  };

  this.addUserToConference = function(userJSON) {
    var conferences = self.conferences();

    for (var c = 0; c < conferences.length; c += 1) {
      // Step 2: Find the conference with the required id
      if (conferences[c].props.id === userJSON.ConferenceId) {
        // Step 3: We're pushing to an observableArray, so no need
        // to worry about Step 4.
        conferences[c].users.push(userJSON);
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  };

};

ko.applyBindings(new ConferenceList(conferencesData));
```

Comment: Can't seem to figure out how everything should work... I've updated my post with the rest of the details. Can you please update your post?

Comment: You still needed to add an `observableArray` to store users. I've made a working example here: https://jsfiddle.net/nnohxh6h/ The most important thing you need to do is design how data, viewmodels and UI work together. If you keep writing `$root` or `$parent` too much, you might need to reconfigure. I've moved the `addUser` method to the `Conference` view model to simplify stuff.

Comment: Thanks, there's one issue though:  I need to be able to edit an existing user/newly added user, (object and DOM). Check the updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pr9dbhq6/

Comment: The users are currently "plain" js objects. If you want to be able to edit them, you'll have to map the objects to a `User` viewmodel with observable properties.

Comment: Please see this post regarding the above problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37502339/make-inner-object-properties-observable-editable-within-array-of-objects

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var obj = [  
   {  
      "ConferenceUsers":[  
         {  
            "Id":3006,
            "ConferenceId":8,
            "Name":null,
            "Email":"mail@lala.com",
            "UserName":null,
            "PhoneNumber":"234234234234",
            "ChannelId":null,
            "State":null,
            "Type":null,
            "RecordingId":null
         }
      ],
      "Id":8,
      "Subject":"YYYhaaaaa",
      "StartTime":"2016-05-29T18:30:00",
      "EndTime":"2016-05-29T19:30:00",
      "OrganizerEmail":"elpas@live.com",
      "OrganizerName":"dasdasd",
      "Pin":"6402",
      "BridgeId":null,
      "State":null
   },
   {  
      "ConferenceUsers":[  
         {  
            "Id":3013,
            "ConferenceId":12,
            "Name":null,
            "Email":"dsfdfsdfdsf@dfdfdf.com",
            "UserName":null,
            "PhoneNumber":null,
            "ChannelId":null,
            "State":null,
            "Type":null,
            "RecordingId":null
         }
      ],
      "Id":12,
      "Subject":"dsfsdfdsfsdf",
      "StartTime":"2016-05-31T22:00:00",
      "EndTime":"2016-05-31T23:00:00",
      "OrganizerEmail":"d@adssad.com",
      "OrganizerName":"dsfdsfsdf",
      "Pin":"3402",
      "BridgeId":null,
      "State":null
   }
];


/* Iterate all conferences */
for (var i in obj) {

  /* Find conference with ID = 8 */
  if (obj[i].Id === 8) {

    /* Add a new user to the conference */
    obj[i].ConferenceUsers.push({

      "Id":1111,
      "ConferenceId":1,
      "Name":null,
      "Email":"test@example.com",
      "UserName":null,
      "PhoneNumber":null,
      "ChannelId":null,
      "State":null,
      "Type":null,
      "RecordingId":null

    });

    break;
  }
}

console.log(obj); // output result
```