# Edit newly added items within array of objects and update DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpzpmgkj/1/).

The **array of objects** looks like below:

```
var data = [{
  "ConferenceUsers": [{
    "Id": 3006,
    "ConferenceId": 8,
    "Name": null,
    "Email": "mail@lala.com",
    "UserName": null,
    "PhoneNumber": "234234234234"
  }],
  "Id": 8,
  "Subject": "YYYhaaaaa",
  "StartTime": "2016-05-29T18:30:00",
  "EndTime": "2016-05-29T19:30:00",
  "OrganizerEmail": "elpas@live.com",
  "OrganizerName": "dasdasd",
}, {
  "ConferenceUsers": [{
    "Id": 3013,
    "ConferenceId": 12,
    "Name": null,
    "Email": "dsfdfsdfdsf@dfdfdf.com",
    "UserName": null,
    "PhoneNumber": null
  }],
  "Id": 12,
  "Subject": "dsfsdfdsfsdf",
  "StartTime": "2016-05-31T22:00:00",
  "EndTime": "2016-05-31T23:00:00",
  "OrganizerEmail": "d@adssad.com",
  "OrganizerName": "dsfdsfsdf"
}];
```

I need to be able to add and edit new `ConferenceUsers`.

Adding new users works but I can't edit them.

**ConferenceUser ViewModel:**

```
var ConferenceUser = function (user) {
    this.ConferenceId = ko.observable(user.ConferenceId);
    this.Email = ko.observable(user.Email);
    this.Id = ko.observable(user.Id);
    this.Name = ko.observable(user.Name);
    this.PhoneNumber = ko.observable(user.PhoneNumber);
};
```

**ConferenceList ViewModel and mappings:**

```
var createConferenceUser = function (user) {
    return new ConferenceUser(user);
};

var ConferenceList = function(conferencesJSON) {
  var self = this;

  var users = [];
  for (i = 0; i < conferencesJSON.length; i++) {
      users.push(conferencesJSON[i].ConferenceUsers);
  }

  this.conferences = ko.observableArray(conferencesJSON.map(createConference));
  this.conferenceUsers = ko.observableArray(users.map(createConferenceUser));

  this.addConference = function(conferenceJSON) {
    self.conferences.push(createConference(conferenceJSON));
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ConferenceList(data));
```

**Q:** How can I update the existing / newly added `ConferenceUsers` and the DOM also, like in the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gpzpmgkj/1/)?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the question. The properties *are* observables, right? How/why did you conclude that they are not?

Comment: Post title edited. If you can have a look on the fiddle I think you'll understand what I'm trying to achieve. I need to be able to update the existing/newly added users and DOM)

Comment: You know your `updateUser` function is empty, right?

Comment: I think you're heading in the right direction, but you need to reconfigure your `Conference` viewmodel and check your data-binds. I can explain some more stuff in an answer later today, but I guess that with some pointers, you'll be able to figure this out yourself. Main points: you didn't map the plain objects to your user viewmodels (`foreach: Conference.users`)! https://jsfiddle.net/ntdxu98e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I commented: if you were to actually use the `ConferenceUser` view models with the observable properties, you would probable able to figure out how to both *create new*, and *edit existing* users. I do see some other points of improvement though, so I think it's still worth to formulate an answer to your question:

- The edit/save/cancel logic is cluttering your `Conference` view model and can easily be separated into its own little widget
- The way you're switching between the *Add* and *Update* button UI doesn't work well with knockout

I've written an answer that's more about the architecture because I feel that the answer from your question follows naturally from a well defined separation of concerns. And because I enjoy refactoring :)

Here's my suggestion after having moved stuff around. You can decide for yourself how much of it you'll use, but at least the answer to your question can be found in the code!

**ConferenceList**

Only serves to manage a list of conferences. Could easily be extended with `removeConference` or `getConferencesFromServer` etc.

```
var ConferenceList = function(conferencesJSON) {
  this.conferences = ko.observableArray(conferencesJSON.map(Conference.create));

  this.addConference = function(conferenceJSON) {
    self.conferences.push(Conference.create(conferenceJSON));
  };
};
```

**Conference**

Holds a list of `ConferenceUser` instances and a widget to edit and create new users. **This is where your question is answered:**

```
var Conference = function(conferenceJSON) {
  var self = this;
  this.Id = conferenceJSON.Id;

  // Note that we're mapping the plain objects from the json to
  // ConferenceUser instances!
  this.users = ko.observableArray(
    conferenceJSON.ConferenceUsers.map(ConferenceUser.create));

  this.userEditor = new UserEditor(this.users, this.Id);

  this.onUserClick = function(user, event) {
    self.userEditor.edit(user);
  };
};
```

**ConferenceUser**

This is where we make sure the UI is updated after edits: note that the `Email` and `PhoneNumber` properties are observable. I didn't create observables for all properties to indicate not all properties are meant to be changed in the UI.

```
var ConferenceUser = function(user) {
  this.Email = ko.observable(user.Email);
  this.PhoneNumber = ko.observable(user.PhoneNumber);

  this.ConferenceId = user.ConferenceId;
  this.Id = user.Id;
  this.Name = user.Name;
};
```

I've created a static create method for two reasons:

1. It keeps track of an `id` inside a closure to make sure it's unique
2. It's easy to use inside an `Array.prototype.map` method.

The code:

```
ConferenceUser.create = (function() {
  var id = 0;

  return function(userOptions) {
    // Add an ID if not present in options
    return new ConferenceUser(Object.assign(userOptions, {
      Id: userOptions.Id || id++
    }));
  };
}());
```

**UserEditor**

This is the biggest improvement (I believe) to your code: an editor widget that helps you create, edit and save new users. The methods it exposes are much easier to understand and write because they're not inside your `Conference` viewmodel.

```
var UserEditor = function(users, conferenceId) {
  var self = this;

  // Holds the user that's being edited, is null when
  // creating a new user
  this.editing = ko.observable(null);

  this.phoneInput = ko.observable("");
  this.emailInput = ko.observable("");

  this.clear = function() {
    self.phoneInput("");
    self.emailInput("");
  };

  this.add = function() {
    var newUserOptions = {
      Email: self.emailInput(),
      PhoneNumber: self.phoneInput(),
      ConferenceId: conferenceId
    };
    users.push(ConferenceUser.create(newUserOptions));
    self.clear();
  };

  this.edit = function(user) {
    self.editing(user);

    self.phoneInput(user.PhoneNumber());
    self.emailInput(user.Email());
  };

  this.reset = function() {
    self.editing(null);
    self.clear();
  };

  this.save = function() {
    var currentUser = self.editing();

    currentUser.Email(self.emailInput());
    currentUser.PhoneNumber(self.phoneInput());

    self.reset();
  };

};
```

Now, after all this code, you'll see your HTML is very straight forward. Here's your *edit widget*:

```
<div data-bind="with: userEditor">
  <input type="tel" placeholder="phone number" 
    data-bind="value: phoneInput" />
  <input type="email " placeholder="email" 
    data-bind="value: emailInput" />
  <!-- ko ifnot: editing -->
  <button data-bind="click: add">Add</button>
  <!-- /ko -->
  <!-- ko if: editing -->
  <button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
  <button data-bind="click: reset">Cancel</button>
  <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Kind of a long story to get to the fix, but if you've made it this far: here's an updated fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/e2ox4doj/

Comment: Thanks for your help! How would I update the list via an ajax function ? Tried it, but getting:  `ConferenceListVM.ConferenceList is not a function` See line 9 & 143 within:  https://jsfiddle.net/cgou56uw/

Comment: The `ConferenceListVM` is an _instance_ of the _ConferenceList_ class. If you want to create the instance before the data is loaded, I'd suggest removing the initialization from the constructor to a separate `load` method. Then, you can do `.done(ConferenceVM.load)`. See the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c9xhmg3u/